# match and replace mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have two tables in a database like this:

**ARTICLE TABLE**

```
id | name
------------
1  | Cars
```

**META TABLE**

```
id | post_id | key  | value
---------------------------
1  | 1       | Audi | 42
```

And want to exact match (value) and replace values of two tables (id / post_id) and convert like this:

**NEW ARTICLE TABLE**

```
id | name
------------
42 | Cars
```

**NEW META TABLE**

```
id | post_id | key  | value
---------------------------
1  | 42      | Audi | 42
```

Is this possible? 
Thank you!

Comment: You want to select the records or want to insert in new table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes that the relationship between `article` and `meta` is `article.id` ==> `meta.post_id`.

In `article`, the `id` is being replaced by the related `meta.value`:

```
UPDATE article
INNER JOIN meta ON article.id = meta.post_id
SET id = meta.value
```

For `new_meta`, it looks like you just need to make `post_id` the same as `value`. That could be a misunderstanding due to the test data. If a join is needed just follow the example of the query above.

```
UPDATE meta
SET post_id = value;
```

Comment: Hi Ed, no haven't "new_article" and "new_meta" tables, it's just example for what I want. I look for a solution on the same tables?

Comment: Got it - you mean a `REPLACE` then? That should be doable. I'll post an update shortly.

Comment: Alex - I've updated the answer. The second query is suspiciously easy, making me wonder if I misunderstood what you want to do with the `meta` table. Let me know if that's the case.